# EJB, RMI, Clustering need to distribute processing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, rmi

First off all, thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english.

I created an application that starts 8 threads and these 8 threads run different text search algorithms...it works prety good.

The new problem is, I have 5 Dell machines Core i7, I would like to create a center machine, to deal with client requests and this machine could request to the others machine to process the inputed text.

I searched about RMI and someone toldme about EJB! Hazcastel and others... I´m not able to connect each service in my mind and be able to start coding the application! Could you help me to find a direction to look for or study the correct tecnology for it??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just an ad-hoc project you can write your own client application that runs on each machine and listens or can be invoked for text processing. You can use sockets or RMI to communicate between the server that distributes the work and the client machines.

Comment: It´s a project that uses a lot of machine resources! I have nine machines, I would like to have one been the manager to distribute the processors to the other machines.